# What is the alternative in Harmony OS for shadow in TextView Android?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am writing a custom component that displays text on the screen using Java SDK.
I want to set a shadow on the text that this component renders like setting `shadowRadius`, `shadowColor`, `shadowDx`, `shadowDy` and also get these values that have been set.

In Android, we have `setShadowLayer(float, float, float, int)`, `getShadowColor()`, `getShadowDx()`, `getShadowDy()` and `getShadowRadius()` method in `TextView` which does that for us.

What is the alternative for the above in Harmony OS?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your feedback. As confirmed by the team, Harmony OS does not support these interfaces by now, but will support these in the near future. Please stay tuned on HarmonyOS official websites.